# Different test results in ctest or make check on 32-bit and 64-bit architecture?

Tags: c++, testing, makefile, cmake

1. I have a c++ program compiled with gcc 4.8.2 which give same output
   on 32 bit and 64 bit machine. The project is configured to build
   with cmake.
2. If I run the test as an input file to my program, I get the same
   result on 32 and 64 bit machines but If I add it as a test and run
   make check or ctest, I get different results on 64 bit machine.
3. The test passes on a 32 bit machine but fails on 64 bit machine.  I
   get a totally different output while running test with ctest/ make
   check.
4. I used linuxmint 17 32 and 64 bit versions

.

Comment: Please add the code or the cmake file here for more details